# JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory for wildfly 8.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am trying to migrate my applicaiton from jboss 3.2 to wildfly.. when  I tried to deploy my ear file,  I am getting Following exception..

```
Can't get data source due to JNDI failure, NamingException = JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.MyApp.war:main" from Service Module Loader..
```

is "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" was removed from wildfly 8.0? Is it any alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate the InitialContext just use the default constructor without passing in properties, also ensure there is no jndi.properties file included in your deployment - this should enable the configuration provided by WildFly to be used.